# git clone with ssh issue

Tags: git, ssh

I have generated a public key, private key pair.
I've set the public key to the site.

How to use the console in windows to clone a git repository?
What do I do with the private key?

I keep getting: the remote end hung up unexp.

Thanks

Comment: Don't do anything with the private key. It just sits on your computer.

Comment: try to use this way to finish your problem.[reference URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58872037/how-to-use-the-gitbash-to-clone-data-with-ssh-windows-10-environment/58872674#58872674)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The private key need to be stored:

- in `%HOME%` directory (ig `%HOME%` is not set, set it to %HOMEPATH% (for Vista or Seven)
- under `.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, juste beside your private key `id_rsa`

```
    %HOME%\.ssh\id_rsa      # your private key
    %HOME%\.ssh\id_rsa.pub  # your public key
```

See:

- [GitHub Guide](http://help.github.com/msysgit-key-setup/) for the generating/storing part of those keys.
- [TroubleShooting SSH issues](http://help.github.com/troubleshooting-ssh/)

Both links are for GitHub, which may not be your exact situation, but they still contain valid informations.
Plus, for certain host providers like GitHub, [additional informations need to be set](http://help.github.com/git-email-settings/).

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are using the same user when calling the `git clone` and generating the keys.

For all my permissions problems, [gitolite](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) was a good solution.